# I want to see dialogue box in the salesforce

Tags: visualforce, form

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" showheader="false">
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.script1}"/>
      <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.script2}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.script3}"/>
    <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
    <apex:form >
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
</apex:form>
```

Here is my code.. I added those stylesheet links to my static resources. But it is not working. Plz help me..

Comment: What do you have in the resources?

Comment: What is in the browser inspector console/errors?

Comment: I resolved it & how means for java script insertion I inserted <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.script1}"/> like that...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to implement the jQuery dialog example from the https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

In order to implement this example using Visualforce, you need to make sure you have all the correct resources and that you are referencing them correctly in your page.

I'm not sure what your script1, script2, and script3 resources are but if they are not CSS stylesheets then you should probably be referencing them with , but you do also need the CSS for the example to render correctly. The example has 4 resource files:

- jquery-ui.css
- style.css
- jquery-1.12.4.js
- jquery-ui.js

The .css files should be referenced with  and the js files with